# Hooking browser page cache to browser history with AJAX for SPAs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, browser

I have investigated several solutions to incorporate browser history (back and forward buttons) with an SPA using AJAX. The prevalent solution is using the HTML5 history API such as history.pushState.
There is also the option of using plugins such as:

- jQuery Address
- jQuery BBQ

Although the above methods work well going back and forward, they seem to be bypassing the browser page cache. So if I press the Back button, I could either go back to the server and fetch the data stored in the URL obtained from the browser history, OR, I could get the cached item from the browser cache.
I am not sure how to get the cached item from the browser cache after pressing the back or forward buttons (instead of going back to the server).

Comment: When you perform the ajax request to get the content when the back button was pressed, the browser will return the cached version if caching headers are set for said page to be cached. Another option is to cache it yourself similar to how jQM does it (which would probably be more consistent.)

Comment: I'm using Django and my view doesn't have @never_cache. You think I need to explicitly set the cache control headers?